Reinforcement learning, pre-trained on historical data
I have a problem whereby I want to optimise sharing patterns on social media for numerous independent pages. There are several degrees of freedom, such as the number of article shares, the number of photo shares and so on. I've been thinking of ways to optimise these configurations and am currently exploring reinforcement learning.
Conceptually, at least, I think this makes sense as something that could be done with RL as there is a clear observation space (number article shares, number photo shares...), an action space (e.g. increase article shares by 1, keep photo shares the same etc) and a reward (change in metric such as impressions or traffic). The state on one day is dependent on the state from the previous day with the action applied to it.
The issue I keep coming up against is that, in the literature, RL is set in a context where the agent is generating its own training data by sampling from the environment on line. However, I cannot have an untrained predictor starting from zero in a production environment making bad predictions. What I do have is an abundance of historical data (share configurations and metrics achieved). Is it possible to train an RL predictive model model on historical data, before deploying it to production once it achieves satisfactory results?
